# Split video in html

Tags: html, video, canvas, split, screen

I would like to split two different videos in a hero image at the top of my page, similar to this..

[split screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c4SCx.png)

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oOZY7Yks6hI

I would also like to ad an on hover effect so that when one half of the video is hovered over, that video expands out over the other one.

I am at a bit of a loss as to how to go about this, thinking there may be a way to do it with canvas but not sure.

Comment: Canvas can do the split screen for you. You can draw on canvas using a video element as an image source. You can clip the canvas so that the video appears on half (or triangular half) the canvas. Then you can reclip the canvas so that the remaining video appears on the other half of the canvas. And you can hit-test the canvas to expand the clicked half.

Comment: Thanks for that, I have got to the point where I have clipped the canvas and it is displaying the first video. Cant "reclip" the rest of the canvas. Any tips?

Comment: Sure. `context.clip` is a sticky setting and must be undone by rapping the first clipping code inside `context.save` and `context.restore`. Save and restore work on every context property, including clipping. Cheers!